# Lead round picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, border, picturebox

How to lead round picturebox, i want to add 2px height border in my picturebox. If its important, my picturebox have ellipse-like region. Thanks!

Comment: There's a [Margin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx) property on all controls. Will this do what you want?

Comment: What have you tried? Please post more details as to what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Put your `PictureBox` on a `Panel` which is 4px larger by height and width, and offset the PictureBox by 2px in each dimension. Set the Panel's background color to whatever you want your border color to be.

Comment: @Kim: this is winforms - no HTML or CSS here.

Comment: Do you mean you want a border around the image within the picturebox, or a border around the picturebox its self?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken and understanding you right, using a PNG file will be of more ease. PNG files can hold alpha values with them. Try to make a required dimensional image and try placing it in Picture-Box. Adobe Photoshop will be helpful in making PNG images.